# titanium webview - go to default browser when clicking links

Tags: iphone, webview, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

in titanium, i'm using the webview to display a wordpress blog page, that is already formatted for mobile browser. instead of writing my own interface, this works as a good work around. the apps sole focus isn't the browser.

but my issue lies, when the user clicks a link outside of the initial displayed domain. i only want the main domain to be displayed in the apps browser. if any other link is clicked, that takes the user outside of that domain, i want to have it open in the phones default browser.

can anyone point me in a direction for this. i tried adding a listener to try and catch link clicks, however, i've been unsuccessful.

thanks

Comment: i found a dev who developed something for iphone using the main programming language outside of titanium. seems to have a nice work around for what i'm wanting to do. 

https://github.com/marksands/MSTextView

anyone know how this could be translated javascript? i've read over the api, however, haven't been able to find any solutions. but i am still a newb to all of this.

Answer (score 1):

in [this blog posting](http://blog.clearlyinnovative.com/post/2847924695/titanium-appcelerator-quickie-disable-links-in-webview) I show how to find links in a webpage and change the link behavior. Using the same method, you can intercept the links and redirect to opening the URL in the devices default browser

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to catch the onclick() Event by Javascript inside the WebView (your blog code) and handle this by a custom handler. Maybe you can inject the javascript event handler code into the running WebView through Titanium.

Another solution is to make your blogposts readable for app technology and create a new data interface. This is the way I would do. For that I would use some kind of JSON data format and a simple REST Interface to get the data.

I don't think bove solutions are that simple. If you want an app with "great feeling", you'll have to handle the events by your own. Maybe Phonegap would be a better solution four your problem. But there you will still need a kind of REST/JSON interface for your blog data. The idea behind an app is, that the main code is in your app and you get the content from a remote source. This way you'll get an advantage compared to a simple browser optimized site.